# All fields not selectable to history track

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, formula-field, fields

I have a custom object `Address_vod__c`. All the fields of this object are not coming for selection in History Tracking window. Is there any way I can make such a field (formula field) available there in Set History Tracking functionality of salesforce for `Address_vod__c`? I do not want to create a new history tracking custom object for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can not** track some kind of fields. These fields are:

- Formula
- Roll-up summary
- Auto-number fields
- Created By
- Last Modified By

More about it: [Tracking Field History for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&language=en_US)

I think the ony way to make it work is to create a new extra history object and a trigger for the custom object to track on.